# WinRT - two apps from one base

Tags: windows-runtime, packaging, publishing

I am building a WinRT app which will need to be published in two separate versions, with different data sources (of course also under separate names).

What is the best approach to managing one app base, that can then be published as two different apps? And how can I make sure the resulting packages are truly separate and do not cause issues when both installed on the same machine?

EDIT: Just to be sure - my intentions are definitely not evil (making the Store messy or something like that), the app base was designed to be universal, but the two apps will have very different functionality, content and target audience.

EDIT #2: Additional question: How can I change the default name of the app package that is produced? While testing I noticed that associating a app with one Store name and then with another still keeps the same name of the package. Where can this be configured?

Comment: Is this helpful? - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-resources-and-cd0c6eaa